Calling GitHub API to fetch file from tag doesn't work as expected in bash script
I have an npm script that when I run locally works just fine, but when it's run as part of a CircleCI job, it tries to literally download the file test.json?ref=0.1.0 and that file doesn't exist. GitHub's docs mention to fetch a file from a tag to use the query string ?ref.
...
"scripts": {
  "fetch-tests": "ls -al && curl -L -O -f 'https://api.github.com/repos/<mycompany>/<myrepo>/contents/test.json?ref=0.1.0' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -H \"Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}\" && ls -al",
...


Why is this happening on CircleCI and how can I fix it?

I have no idea why this doesn't work on CircleCI. It could be a difference in cURL versions.
In either case, changing my script to use --get -d 'ref=0.1.0' instead of appending the query string to the url seemed to work.
So instead of
curl -L -O -f 'https://api.github.com/repos/<mycompany>/<myrepo>/contents/test.json?ref=0.1.0' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -H \"Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}\"

I used
curl -L -O -f --get -d 'ref=0.1.0' 'https://api.github.com/repos/<mycompany>/<myrepo>/contents/test.json' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -H \"Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}\"

